# MongoDB - how to project two or more fields from the joined collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following problem and despite of my search, I cannot figure it out...

I have two collections with the following values:

DOCTOROFFICES COLLECTION

```
{ _id: 1, name: "doctoroffice1", appointment_hours:["09:00","10:00","11:00"]}
{ _id: 2, name: "doctoroffice2", appointment_hours:["09:30","11:30"]}
```

DOCTORS COLLECTION

```
{_id: 1, name: "Kostas", lastname: "Pap", tel: "1234567890", doctoroffice: "doctoroffice1", rating: { totalRate: 300, totalVotes: 100 } }
{_id: 2, name: "George", lastname: "Geo", tel: "7890246899", doctoroffice: "doctoroffice1", rating: { totalRate: 400, totalVotes: 200 } }
{_id: 3, name: "Mark", lastname: "Ma", tel: "24689001122", doctoroffice: "doctoroffice2", rating: { totalRate: 450, totalVotes: 310 } }
{_id: 4, name: "Paul", lastname: "Pa", tel: "2244668800", doctoroffice: "doctoroffice2", rating: { totalRate: 40, totalVotes: 10 } }
```

As presented above, I have the collection "Doctoroffices" with (2) doctor offices. Each doctor office comprises of (2) doctors, saved in the collection "Doctors".
My goal is to produce the below JSON answer from my MongoDB:

```
{
   doctorOfficeLabel: "doctoroffice1",
   ratingData: [
      { doctorName: "Kostas",
        doctorLastname: "Pap",
        totalRate: 300,
        totalVotes: 100 },
      { doctorName: "George",
        doctorLastname: "Geo",
        totalRate: 400,
        totalVotes: 200 }
   ]
},
{
   doctorOfficeLabel: "doctoroffice2",
   ratingData: [
      { doctorName: "Mark",
        doctorLastname: "Ma",
        totalRate: 450,
        totalVotes: 310 },
      { doctorName: "Paul",
        doctorLastname: "Pa",
        totalRate: 40,
        totalVotes: 10 }
   ]
}
```

My solution so far is:

```
db.doctoroffices.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
                from: "doctors",
                localField: "name",
                foreignField: "doctoroffice",
                as: "doctor_docs"
              }    
    }, 
    {$unwind: "$doctor_docs"},
    {$project: { 
                 _id: 0,
                 doctorOfficeLabel: "$name",
                 ratingData: {
                                 doctorName: "$doctor_docs.name",
                                 doctorLastname: "$doctor_docs.lastname",
                                 totalRate: "$doctor_docs.rating.totalRate",
                                 totalVotes: "$doctor_docs.rating.totalVotes",
                             }
               }
    }
]
```

The problem here is that more than one objects with the same "doctorOfficeLabel" are created, but I want as many objects as the number of the doctor offices.
I' ve also tried the above code without the {$unwind: "$doctor_docs"}, but the results also weren't as expected.

Can anyone help me with my problem or in case there is not solution to my problem, to propose me a workaround??

Thank you very much for your time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try doing formatting on the client side but if you really want to do it on server side, you can use `$map`.

Server Side

Something like

```
db.doctoroffices.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: "doctors",
            localField: "name",
            foreignField: "doctoroffice",
            as: "doctor_docs"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            doctorOfficeLabel: "$name",
            ratingData: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$doctor_docs",
                    as: "result",
                    in: {
                        doctorName: "$$result.name",
                        doctorLastname: "$$result.lastname",
                        totalRate: "$$result.rating.totalRate",
                        totalVotes: "$$result.rating.totalVotes",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Client Side

```
db.doctoroffices.aggregate({
    $lookup: {
        from: "doctors",
        localField: "name",
        foreignField: "doctoroffice",
        as: "doctor_docs"
    }
}).map(a => {
    var doctoroffice = {
        doctorOfficeLabel: a.name
    };
    doctoroffice.ratingData = a.doctor_docs.map(b => {
        var doctordoc = {
            doctorName: b.name,
            doctorLastname: b.lastname,
            totalRate: b.rating.totalRate,
            totalVotes: b.rating.totalVotes
        }
        return doctordoc;
    });
    return doctoroffice;
});
```

Comment: *"You should try doing formatting on the client side..."* So show them how! Chances are when the person is asking to basically reshape a result in a way that does not really reduce data from the server, then they do not understand how to manipulate the resulting data structure in code. When you actually show them it takes all of "two" lines of code opposed to a long winded aggregation pipeline stage, then the *"lightbulb"* goes of and people generally get it.

Comment: @Veeram I thought that it is important not to move a lot of data through the connection. But as I understand, it is preferrable the server to consume lesser process power, despite the fact that more data produces than needed. And finally the requested data to shape in the client. Could you show me the way to do it if it is that simple?? Thank you very much for your time!!

Comment: You are welcome. I have edited the post to include the client side version.